# Is there an adaptable way of presenting a variable in a Tkinter window so that it changes with the rest of the program?

Tags: python, tkinter

Say I had an algorithm like this (because I do):

```
from tkinter import *

x = 0 # For Example
window = Tk()
#window.minsize(Whatever, Whatever Else)
label = Label(window, text=x)
label.pack()
```

I also want to change x regularly during the programme to the value of a sensor but I'll just use a simple loop to show what I'm after:

```
for loop in range(4):
    x = x+1 #If, say, the sensor value goes up by 1 each time
```

Is there anything I can do to update the text in the window (on the label) every time x changes (which isn't specific to this code so anyone can use it)?

Comment: you could use `x = tkinter.IntVar()` for value and `Label( textvariable=x)` to display it. But you would have to use `x.set(x.get()+1)` instead of `x = x+1`. Other problem is to update widget/Label when you run loop or other code which blocks `mainloop` (which updates/redraws all widgets in window) - it would need `root.update()` to force `tkinter to redraw widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter` has special classes to keep values `IntVar()`, `StringVar()`, `DoubleVar()` which can be used with widget to automatically update text in `Label` or get value from Entry (etc.)

But it has to use `.get()` and `.set()`

Other problem is that loop and long running code may block `mainloop` which redraws widgets. Sometimes it may need `window.update()` to forcer tkinter to redraw widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk

def change():
    x.set(x.get()+1)
    window.after(1000, change)

window = tk.Tk()

x = tk.IntVar(value=0) # after creating Tk()

label = tk.Label(window, textvariable=x)
label.pack()

change()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This design pattern solves the common issue you have.

Your GUI should be an observer of the data it presents. When this data changes, the changing component should notify the observer (GUI) of a state change.